# GAQL metrics.X is effected by segments.Y?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I have this GAQL:

```
  var query = 'SELECT \
    customer.id,\
    customer.descriptive_name,\
    group_placement_view.placement_type,\
    group_placement_view.display_name,\
    metrics.average_cpm\
 FROM group_placement_view\
 WHERE\
    group_placement_view.placement_type IN ("YOUTUBE_CHANNEL")\
    AND campaign.advertising_channel_type = "VIDEO"\
    AND segments.date BETWEEN "'+ fromDate.query_date + '" AND "' + toDate.query_date + '"\
    AND metrics.impressions >= 100\
    AND metrics.average_cpm > 1000000'
```

IIUC it segments data by days. Correct?
`segments.date`

But the `metrics.impressions >= 100` relates to the aggregated data of the whole period. Right?

Answer (score 0):

No, the metrics.impressions >= 100 relates to each individual row, not the aggregated data.